# How to stop a button from triggering multiple events from previous event listeners

Tags: javascript, html, forms, addeventlistener, event-listener

I have a table of transactions and each have a edit button to edit the data and then save it to the database. My issue is if I click to edit one and then multiple others they all save using the same data. So if I click the first five edit buttons, then on the last one I clicked on I change the quantity to 5, all the ones I have previously clicked on also change to 5 after saving. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzKtd.png)

I have tried removing the event listeners for the save and edit buttons but to no avail. It seems like the issue is because the event listeners are remaining in the background and are running because the save buttons are all the same class name as well as the edit buttons. Everything works fine as long as you hit cancel, but if you click on one edit button, and then another you have two instances. What is a way I can delete the saveBtn event listener when they click a different edit button?

```
const csvToTable = (csv, transactionIdsAtIndex) => {
    let rows = csv.trim().split(/\r?\n|\r/);
    let table = '';
    let tableRows = '';
    let tableHeader = '';
    rows.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
        let tableColumns = '';
        let columns = row.split(','); // split/separate the columns in a row
        if (rowIndex === 0) {
            columns.unshift('');
        } else {
            columns.unshift('<button class="btn edit">Edit</button>');
        }
        columns.forEach((column) => {
            tableColumns += rowIndex == 0 ? '<th>' + column + '</th>' : '<td>' + column + '</td>';
        });
        if (rowIndex == 0) {
            tableHeader += `<tr id="${rowIndex}">` + tableColumns + '</tr>';
        } else {
            tableRows += `<tr id="${rowIndex}">` + tableColumns + '</tr>';
        }
    });
    table += '<table>';
    table += '<thead>';
        table += tableHeader;
    table += '</thead>';
    table += '<tbody>';
        table += tableRows;
    table += '</tbody>';
    table += '</table>';
    if (csvTable.classList.contains('hidden')) {
        csvTable.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
    csvTable.innerHTML += table;
    downloadBtn.classList.remove('hidden');
    handleEvents(transactionIdsAtIndex);
}

const handleEvents = (transactionIdsAtIndex) => {
    const editBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.edit');
    editBtn.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', function editTransaction() {
        editTransactionForm(transactionIdsAtIndex[btn.parentElement.parentElement.id]);
        btn.removeEventListener('click', editTransaction);
    }));
}

const editTransactionForm = (id) => {
    console.log('editing')
    editForm.classList.remove('hidden');
    downloadMenu.classList.add('hidden');
    downloadBtn.classList.add('hidden');

    api.call('Get', {typeName: 'FuelTransaction', search: {id: id}}, result => {
        const transaction = result[0];
        volume.value = (transaction.volume / 3.785412534257983).toFixed(2);
        cost.value = transaction.cost.toFixed(2);
        pricePerUnit.value = (cost.value / volume.value).toFixed(2);
        fuelType.value = transaction.productType;

        saveBtn.addEventListener('click', function validateFormData () {
            console.log('saving');
            let valid = true;
            if (isNaN(volume.value) || isNaN(cost.value) || isNaN(pricePerUnit.value)) {
                valid = false;
                popupText.textContent = 'Input must be a number';
                popup.classList.remove('hidden');
            } else if (!volume.value || !cost.value || !pricePerUnit.value) {
                valid = false;
                popupText.textContent = 'Missing input';
                popup.classList.remove('hidden');
            } else if (fuelType.value.length === 0) {
                valid = false;
                popupText.textContent = 'Must enter a fuel type';
                popup.classList.remove('hidden');
            }
            if (valid) {
                transaction.volume = Number(volume.value * 3.785412534257983);
                transaction.cost = Number(cost.value);
                transaction.productType = String(fuelType.value);
                popupText.textContent = 'Saving...';
                popup.classList.remove('hidden');
                api.call('Set', {typeName: 'FuelTransaction', entity: transaction},
                () => {
                    saveBtn.removeEventListener('click', validateFormData);
                    popup.classList.add('hidden');
                    editForm.classList.add('hidden');
                    downloadMenu.classList.remove('hidden');
                    getTransactionDetails();
                },
                err => {
                    popupText.textContent = 'Error saving transaction';
                    popup.classList.remove('hidden');
                    console.log(err)
                })
            }
        })
        
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to identify the button and its associated dataset, you can use the data attribute and set it while inserting the button.

```
<button data-transactionID="21">Text<Button>
```

then in your function, you can check which id the corresponding dataset had. It is important to pass the event into the function.

```
let id = event.target.dataset.transactionID
```